# Storing large file of 100 MB in Mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql

I want to store Large file of 100MB to 1GB in MongoDB just like BLOB object and later on can easier retrieve it. The programming language that i am using is PHP
Please guide me in this sense.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use GridFS for this as normally MongoDB documents are limited to 16MB. See the overview and examples in the PHP documentation at http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongogridfs.php

Comment: I used the below command to upload a zipped folder of 254MB.  C:\mongodb\bin>mongofiles.exe -d users put c:\SWSetup.zip But the document it created as also 262 MB. I thought it would save the data in chunks of document. Can you tell me what can be the max size of a single document.

Comment: Using mongo gridfs in PHP i am unable to upload more than 16 MB of file.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum size of a document in MongoDB 1.8 and above is 16Mb.

Previously it was 4Mb. GridFS enables one to seamlessly spread a single file across many documents. If you inspect the actual documents in MongoDB you will notice many separate documents, but through GridFS they will seamlessly appear as a single file.

Does that answer the question?

Comment: Steve i have upload 256MB zipped file. It created 256 MB document though i used PHP GridFS. From the database i checked it has chunks of 25MB. But the problem is that i am unable to download the zipped file. as it cannot load 256MB to memory. Any solution to this problem.